# Conditional formatting of cells based on other cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm working in sheets and I've been doing quite some coding past few days. Last thing to finish my work is getting some conditional formatting done.

[image]

I have a spreadsheet with some names in the selected part on the top. When I enter one of those names in the cells in the selected range below, I want that name to change color in the selected part on top.

I've been trying to get this done for quite some time, but I can't get it right. Anyone knows if this is possible?

I tried using conditional formatting with custom formulas, but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
=match(A1,tocol($A$14:$C$16),0)
```

Result:

[image]

Don't forget to adapt ranges.